# Let $G$ be a group, $k$ be a positive integer, $G^k=\{ g^k \mid g\in G\}$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic iff every subgroup of $G$ has a set form $G^k$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, alternative-proof, cyclic-groups

Let $G$ be a group, $k$ be a positive integer, $G^k=\{g^k \mid g\in G\}$. Prove that $G$ is cyclic iff every subgroup of $G$ has a set form $G^k$.

Someone gives a proof here:
[Group $G$ is cyclic $\iff$ every subgroup of $G$ has the form $G^k$, where $G^k=\{g^k\mid g\in G\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2464037/group-g-is-cyclic-iff-every-subgroup-of-g-has-the-form-gk-where-gk)

But I was trying to create a isomorphism between $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ depending on whether $G$ is finite as they must be isomorphic if $G$ is cyclic. And the set $H=\{G^k \mid 0\le k\le o(G)\}$ exhausts $G$.

I got lost trying to prove that all the sets $G^k$ are not only groups but abelian ones. Also, if I to compose an isomorphism like  $\varphi:G^k\to k \mathbb{Z},g_n\to kn$ when $G$ is an infinite group, how to make $\varphi$ bijective?

Comment: Not a huge algebra person, but it sounds kind of ambitious to take a statement about subgroups and turn it into a statement about isomorphisms into $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.  Maybe settle for an injective homomorphism?

Comment: That the groups are abelian follows from the fact that $g^a g^b = g{a+b} = g^b g^a$ (as it is just a word written like $ggg\dots ggg$)